# Adding two numerical columns makes the newly created column unknown

Tags: r, format

I have a dataset with two columns which are classed as numerical data but when I add the columns together the class of the newly created column becomes 'unknown'. I find this particularly bizarre as in 50 or so other datasets the newly created column is indeed numeric but I have a handful of cases where it comes out unknown.

Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to rectify it?

I have tried to set the column afterwards to be numeric - `x$Total <- as.numeric(x$Total)` but this does nothing and it still remains unknown.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: No one can help you without looking at the data. Please share the sample dataset and always try to ask a question with reproducible data. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.